# Is there a way to validate user input using a variable format?

Tags: python-3.x

The project I'm working on is an Airplane class that contains lists of seats. Below is an example of the list of seats. I am trying to create a try/except block within my book_seat() to check if the user inputs a correct string to match one of the seats, ie. 'Seat 1' or even up to 'Seat 200'. Is there a way I can scan the list via a format or maybe a regular expression? I am having trouble thinking of a better way to ask this question so here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
while True:
    try:
        user_input = input("Please enter a seat number to book. (ie. 'Seat 1'))
        if user_input == 'Seat {}'.format(int):
            execute_function()
    except:
        print("sorry, you're entry is not valid. Please try again")
```

```
[['Seat 1', Seat('Economy',False)], ['Seat 2', Seat('Economy',False)], ['Seat 3', Seat('Economy',False)], ['Seat 4', Seat('Economy',False)], ['Seat 5', Seat('Economy',False)], ['Seat 6', Seat('Economy',False)], ['Seat 7', Seat('Economy',False)], ['Seat 8', Seat('Business',False)], ['Seat 9', Seat('Business',False)], ['Seat 10', Seat('First',False)]]
```

Comment: Why would you have the user input `"Seat 1"` when you could just have them input `1`? The regular expression you're looking for is `r"Seat \d+"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary and a key to get the value:

```
dic = {'Economy': [1,  2,  3],
   'Business': [4, 5, 6]}


user_input = input("Please enter a seat number to book (ie. 'Seat 1')  :  ")
i = [int(s) for s in user_input.split() if s.isdigit()]
if i[0] in (dic['Economy'])  :
    execute_function()
else:

    print("sorry, you're entry is not valid. Please try again")
```